# solr range query errors

Tags: solr

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?wt=json&q=lat:[35%20to%2038] results in

```
org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException: Cannot parse 'lat:[35 to 38]': Encountered " <RANGEIN_GOOP> "38 "" at line 1, column 11.
Was expecting:
    "]"
```

This is a pretty basic range query and this error will prevent us from using SOLR for our projects

Answer (score 22):

Try 'TO' in upper-case.

Comment: You're right. lowercase 'to' appears to work, but 'TO' works as it should.

Comment: yup, it *has* to be upper-case

Comment: correct it has to uppercase and all fields of table are case sensitive. Also do not forget to keep expression inside quote ' '

Answer (score 0):

Switched default to use dismax instead of lucene parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
/_search?q=lat:[35 TO 38]
or
/_search?q=lat:[35%20TO%2038]
```

**Working & Tested the same.**

```
https://search-xxxx-scyleqdxxxxx57yi4m.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/id/_search?q=id:2017-10-28&size=100

https://search-xxxx-scyleqdxxxxx57yi4m.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/id/_search?q=v:[0%20TO%20100]&size=100

https://search-xxxx-scyleqdxxxxx57yi4m.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com/id/_search?q=id:[2017-10-26%20TO%202017-10-27]&size=100
```